# Local avoidance together with any-angle types of A* Pathfinding

Tags: unity, c#, ai, path-finding, steering-behaviors

Recently I have been implementing the Block A* any-angle path-finding algorithm in a project I have, for which I need extremely efficient results due to the large number of NPCs. However, I still do not know exactly how to handle the problem of local avoidance between the NPCs moving at the same time in the same scene.

So, my question is this: what is the best method to implement local avoidance with any-angle path-finding? Just testing for LOS and steering to the tangent of the predicted encounter is a good enough solution or should a specific AI implementation be included within the pathfinding routine?

I would highly appreciate references (academical or not) with state-of-the-art implementations of local avoidance for me to explore the most recent developments in that field.

Many thanks.

Comment: Just an idea, but what about adding a repulsive force between close NPCs, like the separation behavior in a Boids flocking simulation?

Answer (score 1):

I have no academical references but  when I faced this problem I integrated local avoidance AI into my path finding.

Assuming that from your path finding you have a "next point to bee reached" call it NEXT, in the ai while reaching NEXT cast one or more short rais forward of your NPC :

[image]

If its blocked by another NPC chose a near point left or right (so that NEXT is still "visible"), reache the near point then procede to NEXT. You can also decelarate/stop for a random time waiting for less traffic.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. That's pretty much what I have been planning to do. However, the tricky part is precisely how to decide what is near point to left or right or whatever, in a smooth and inteligent way so other moving NPCs won't choose the same and create even more trouble. Or at best, to avoid the bouncing around or getting stuck in a corner after doing the avoidance.
So, that's precisely what I am after, and your answer helped me put it more clearly: interesting ways of making that refined calculation.

Comment: I do almost that but cast a few rays out so I know if the other AI is on the left or right of me and then move the other way. It works well most of the time. Just need some tweaking. 3 rays each side 0.2r, 0.5r, 1.5r then test against an offset boundingsphere with a rad of 200

Comment: You may also want to look at [a few simple rules](http://images.slideplayer.com/19/5887226/slides/slide_3.jpg) which would reduce ambiguity. ;)